# undefined method `all' for Ransack::Search<class: Post, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack

I'm new in ruby and rails, I want to ask a question.

I'm getting error:

```
undefined method `all' for Ransack::Search<class: Post, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

The error lines is from:

```
@posts = @search.all
```

My html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title_or_body_contains %>
<%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

My entity controller:

```
def index
    @search = Post.search(params[:search])
    @posts = @search.all
end
```

My application controller:

```
def site_search
    @search = Post.search(params[:search])
    @search_posts = @search.all
end
```

My gem:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.5.0.beta1'
gem 'ransack',    github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: try `@search.result` instead.

Comment: it run, but for searching isn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@search.result`, I think `@search.all` was for the metasearch gem.